# Right approach for using GPS on iOS

Tags: ios, gps, position, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to implement the use of gps in my app, but I'm not sure about the right approach for doing this.

My app has the following design:
* home page with some buttons that redirect to the following views:
 - list of locations (with distance from the current position)
 - detail of selected location (with distance from the current position)
 - map (with detail of the selected location)

I've implemented the CLLocationManagerDelegate in the map view, but I understand that I need the current position also in the other views to calculate distances.
What is the best approach? Do I have to support the CLLocationManagerDelegate and calculate current position in each view? Or maybe do I have to support the delegate only in my homepage and store the current location in a global variable?

Suggestions will be really appreciated!!

Thanks,
yassa

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me is to implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate as a singleton class, so that you can refer to it everywhere in your app.